# Call a method from abstract class c#

Tags: c#

I need to call `CalculateMonthlyPay()` method from `Employee` class in `FullTimeEmployee` and `PartTimeEmployee` classes, any idea how to do it?

this is my code:

```
public abstract class Employee
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public abstract decimal CalculateMonthlyPay();
}

public class FullTimeEmployee
{
    public decimal Salary { get; set; }
}

public class PartTimeEmployee
{
    public decimal HourlyRate { get; set; }
    public double HoursWorked { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You defined the method as abstract in Employee which means you have to implement Employee and then override the method in your sub classes.  Read the docs on how to use abstract base cleasses: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/abstract

Comment: Did you try just calling them? What prevented you from doing it? Did you actually set up the inheritance properly? Usually if you define an abstract class, you're going to have something inherit from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
public class FullTimeEmployee : Employee
{​​​​​​​
    public decimal Salary {​​​​​​​ get; set; }​​​​​​​

    public override decimal CalculateMonthlyPay()
    {​​​​​​​
        //code here
    }​​​​​​​


}​​​​​​​
```